# Who were the villagers that Mat sent to keep the river from being dammed?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Last Battle - farmers at the river](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/the-last-battle-farmers-at-the-river)

In the battle at the Fields of Merrilor, Mat makes what seems to be a strange decision.  He sends a group of villagers, including women and children, along with a token band of soldiers, and Jur Grady, to defend the river and prevent the forces of the Dark One from blocking the flow of water.

The defenses hold for some time (I believe one or two characters commented on being surprised that the river stayed unblocked for as long as it did), but then are overrun and slaughtered.

Jur Grady was apparently the only survivor, following orders to hide nearby and wait for a signal.  Jur was sickened by the slaughter, what he felt was the senseless waste of the lives of innocent people, and most of all that women and children were sacrificed for such an apparently meaningless goal.

> However, towards the end of the battle, suddenly all of the villagers reappear and attack the forces of the Dark One.  Where did they all come from?  How did they reappear?

Comment: @NikolaiDante Alright, I need a nap, apparently.  That's both my questions duplicates.  My apologies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They were the reviving villagers that the Band ran into a couple books prior at

> Hinderstap.

When he was on his way back to Andor with the Dragon/Cannon designs, he tried to stay the night in a cursed village where the people were effectively magic zombies. He threw them in the fray to make it look like the day had been won by the Shadow until, oops lol zombies. It really creeped the Dreadlords out, enough to get to them and gut them.

It was a Mat sort of move.

Comment: I think that may be it.  I was thinking it was a bubble-of-evil thing, but couldn't remember a specific instance (it's been years since I read most of the books, and I don't remember that much of the previous book). The name of the village was mentioned in AMOL, but I don't have my copy handy.

Comment: Thanks I totally missed this when I read it. That *is* a Mat sort of move